# Discrete OnTouchListener events

Tags: android, touch

Why does View.OnTouchListener() works so freaky when I just ask it to increment 1?

```
    public class Clicker extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clicker);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (v != null) {

            v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                int count = 3123;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent me) {
                    v.setSelected(me.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                    count = count + 1;
                    t.setText(String.format("%d",count));
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
1 click increments 2 or 3 points.

Comment: onTouch will call more than one time like ACtion_down , action_up etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onTouch method is called for many different touch events, including ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_UP. Just by clicking the button, this method is called twice, once for the down press, and once when your finger is lifted. In order to count only once when the button is pressed, you would need to write something like this:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            count += 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The method:

`onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent me)`

is called for every touch event. For a click you will receive two events`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` also if you move the finger you can receive also a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

Comment: how then can I catch MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN only?

Comment: Touch event listener is called for every touch event. Maybe OnClickListener is better for what you need. Or you can make an if statement to test your if the action passed by the method is ACTION_DOWN.